Count the occurrence of each series for each time value
I've made a dataset for the occurrences of solar flares, divided into 4 categories (M5-M9.9, X1-X5, X5-X10, X10+) and when the flares occurred.
Subset of Total DataFrame
here you can see a subset of my DataFrama, and as you can seein the year 1997, several solar flares occurred of which 5 M-flares. Of those flares, 4 occurred in November of 1997 (1997.87), how can I plot that as 1997.87 (or 0.10 of the cycle) on the x-axis and 4 on the y-axis.
Also visible is that in 1998.87, one X5-X10 flare occurred and five X1-X5 flares, how I can count the occurrences of each category for each time value?
I have not yet tried anything, for I don't know where to start.

Images of code/data are not acceptable, you must use text for a [mre]. Also provide the matching expected output.

groupby?

@RuthC, thanks, it sort of worked
